# Farthest two points in d-dimensional space

Tags: geometry

> I have N points in D-dimensional space. I need to calculate the farthest Manhattan distance between two points of them.
>
> (2 ≤ N ≤ 100000, 1 ≤ D ≤ 6), the absolute value of the given coordinates is 1000000. [Source](http://www.spoj.com/problems/DISTANCE/)

I tried to sum the coordinates for every point, then calculate the difference between the MIN and MAX value, but this will not work with case like this

> N = 2, D = 2
>
> 4 -4
>
> -7 7
>
> my wrong answer  = 0 - 0 = 0
>
> correct answer = abs(4 - (-7)) + abs(-4 - 7) = 22

I also tried to find the MIN and MAX coordinate for all the D coordinates and maximize the result. But it didn't work too.

I can't find a correct and fast solution, of course brute force will get [ Time limit exceeded ]

Edit: You can find a more detailed description of Joseph's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/477767/275204).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manhattan distance is the $L_1$ metric.
One way to improve over brute-force is to embed your
point set isometrically into $L_\infty$
where the problem is easier to solve (because that's the max metric). Unfortunately, this requires mapping
from $d$ dimensions to $2^d$ dimensions, but in your case it may be worthwhile.
The time complexity is reduced from $O(d n^2)$ [brute-force] to
$O(n 2^d)$.

You can find a discussion in [these UChicago class notes](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~harry/teaching/pdf/lecture1.pdf).

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But it wasn't clear, nevertheless I didn't know about isometric embedding before. I searched about it and found a more detailed answer, then I solved the problem correctly, It's in my updated question now.

Answer (score 0):

It is very interesting problem. I suppose you should look at "Generic Approximation algorithms" of Sariel Har-Peled. He uses approximation algorithm to find diameter of set of points. To find diameter, He computes well separated pairs decomposition.

Comment: The approximation algorithm still run in quadratic time in the worst case. I think for the mentioned problem isometric embedding is the best solution you can come up with, however you still can't use embedding with euclidean distance (see "TFOSS problem" on SPOJ), you have to iterate over the convex hull and for each point find the other point lies on a maximum distance in O(logN) time.

Comment: What is isometric embedding technique? I know, that this problem can be solved via convex hull only in 2 d case

Comment: The technique which Joseph have mentioned in the above answer. you can find a more detailed explanation for it in my edited question. I have solved the problem using it and here is my accepted solution http://ideone.com/hg9DZY